# Xamarin forms: How to set background color for xamarin forms android splash screen?

Tags: xamarin.android, background-color, splash-screen

Following is the splash screen code of my xamarin forms android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/splashbg"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I wanna remove the first bitmap(named splashbg) and provide a background color for the entire page. How to give background color in xamarin android? Currently showing black color.

Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155028/splash-screen-activity-background-color), but not solving my issue.

Try adding **android:color="#00aff0"** for layer list, but not working...

Comment: The link in the question is working, but it takes a couple of builds to change the color. Maybe it is the problem with my testing device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside my splash activity theme i have set:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

then in drawable folder i have background_splash.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:drawable="@color/colorSplash"/>

  <item>

    <bitmap
      android:gravity="center"
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:src="@drawable/logosplash"/>

  </item>


</layer-list>
```

and the color is in the values folder, colors.xml:

```
<color name="colorSplash">#2674B5</color>
```